# Missing support for Docker Compose in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

I created new .NET Web application project and I am trying to add Docker Compose support but the option is missing.

[image]

There is only Docker support available in the menu.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I updated VS from version 17.8.1 to version 17.8.2 and Docker Desktop to 4.25.2 (the previous version I think I had 4.25.1) and when I created new project now the option is there

[image]